# Pivot is not sorting [Quick Sort]

Tags: java, quicksort

I have my Quick sort class here

```
package week4;

class QuickSort<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    public void display(T[] array) {
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index < array.length - 1; index++)
            System.out.print(array[index] + ", ");
        System.out.println(array[index]);
    }

    private void swap(T[] a, int i, int j) {
        T temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
        display(a);
    }

    public void order(T[] a, int i, int j) {
        if (a[i].compareTo(a[j]) > 0)
            swap(a, i, j);
    }

    public void sortFirstMiddleLast(T[] a, int first, int mid, int last) {
        order(a, first, mid); // make a[first] <= a[mid]
        order(a, mid, last); // make a[mid] <= a[last]
        order(a, first, mid); // make a[first] <= a[mid]
    }

    public int partition(T[] arr, int first, int last) {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        sortFirstMiddleLast(arr, first, mid, last);

        swap(arr, mid, last - 1);
        int pivotIndex = last - 1;
        T pivot = arr[pivotIndex];

        int indexFromLeft = first + 1;
        int indexFromRight = last - 2;

        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            while (arr[indexFromLeft].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
                indexFromLeft++;

            while (arr[indexFromRight].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
                indexFromRight--;

            if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight) {
                swap(arr, indexFromLeft, indexFromRight);
                indexFromLeft++;
                indexFromRight--;
            } else
                done = true;
        }

        // place pivot between Smaller and Larger subarrays
        swap(arr, pivotIndex, indexFromLeft);
        pivotIndex = indexFromLeft;

        // Smaller = a[first pivotIndex-1]
        // Pivot = a[pivotIndex]
        // Larger = a[pivotIndex + 1..the last]
        return pivotIndex;
    }
}

public class Project1B {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        QuickSort<Integer> ob = new QuickSort<Integer>();

        Integer[] arr = { 10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5 };

        int n = arr.length;

        ob.partition(arr, 0, n - 1);

        System.out.println("sorted array");
        ob.display(arr);
    }
}
```

My output is this..:

8, 7, 10, 9, 1, 5

8, 7, 5, 9, 1, 10

5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10

5, 7, 1, 9, 8, 10

5, 7, 1, 8, 9, 10

sorted array

5, 7, 1, 8, 9, 10

My problem is that the pivot doesn't get sorted for some reason and i am not sure why...I've tried to debug and tried to google but I'm having trouble to figuring it out...

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. "please help" isn't a problem description that enables us to help you. Clearly describe the errors you see, for example with some example data output.

Comment: I am just currently having a problem trying to pass my array int[] arr into the function partion.

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a somewhat confused implementation of the quicksort algorithm.

Firstly, I don't see the point of having the `sortFirstMiddleLast` method.  We certainly can't say that after calling this method that the three numbers are in their correct place in the array.  For example, what happens if these three numbers happen to be the three largest numbers in the array?  It's also not part of the quicksort algorithm.  I would get rid of this method.

Following on from this we must then include the first and last elements of the array when swapping elements to ensure they are on the right side of the pivot.  So replace the lines

```
        swap(arr, mid, last - 1);
        int pivotIndex = last - 1;
        T pivot = arr[pivotIndex];

        int indexFromLeft = first + 1;
        int indexFromRight = last - 2;
```

with

```
        swap(arr, mid, last);
        int pivotIndex = last;
        T pivot = arr[pivotIndex];

        int indexFromLeft = first;
        int indexFromRight = last - 1;
```

Next we need to take a look at these two `while` loops:

```
            while (arr[indexFromLeft].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
                indexFromLeft++;

            while (arr[indexFromRight].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
                indexFromRight--;
```

The first loop is guaranteed to terminate with `indexFromLeft` within the range being sorted, because at some point `arr[indexFromLeft]` will be a number that is greater than or equal to the pivot.  This includes the pivot itself if the pivot happens to be the largest number, because you put the pivot at the end of the subarray we are sorting.

On the other hand, the second loop will terminate if `arr[indexFromRight]` is smaller than (or equal to) the pivot.  However, if the pivot itself is the smallest number in the range being sorted, `indexFromRight` will stray out of this range.  In fact, if the pivot happens to be the smallest number in the whole array, there is nothing to stop this loop 
falling off the beginning of the array and throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

We can avoid this situation by adding a condition that prevents `indexFromRight` from going outside the range we are sorting:

```
            while (indexFromRight > first && arr[indexFromRight].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
                indexFromRight--;
```

Finally, your code appears to ignore a key aspect of how the quicksort algorithm works: it is recursive.  Once the pivot has been put in the correct place, you must then recursively sort the two sub-arrays on either side of it.  To do this:

- Declare `partition` to return `void` rather than an `int`, and remove the line `return pivotIndex;`.  You aren't doing anything with the return value so we may as well get rid of it.
- Add the following lines to the end of your `partition` method to recursively sort the sub-arrays:

  ```
      partition(arr, first, pivotIndex - 1);
      partition(arr, pivotIndex + 1, last);
  ```
- Add the following line to the start of `partition`:

  ```
  if (first >= last) { return; }
  ```

  If `first == last` then you are sorting a 1-element array or sub-array, and that can be sorted by doing nothing.  Similarly, if `first > last`, the sub-array to sort is empty and that can also be sorted by doing nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it like this:

```
public static int [] quickSort (int [] array, int first, int last){
        int pivot = array[last/2];


        while (!isSorted(array)) {
            int left = first;
            int right = last;
            while (true) {
                while (array[left] < pivot && left < last) {
                    left++;
                }
                while (array[right] >= pivot && right > first) {
                    right--;
                }
                if (array[left] > array[right]) {
                    swap(array, left, right);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
                }
                if (left >= right)
                    break;
                if (right - left == 1)
                    break;
            }
        }

    return array;
}
```

this method checks if the array is sorted or not yet:

```
private static boolean isSorted(int [] array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] > array[i+1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: -1, it might solve the problem, but for the wrong reason. It will not be QuickSort anymore, but a slightly different sorting algorithm (related to BogoSort). Checking if the array is sorted and "try again" is not part of QuickSort, the problem of the code is somewhere else. Also, your solution would result in IndexOutOfBoundsException.